# @commands.has permissions(administrator=true) command has no attribute has_permisions error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I am coding a bot, here the whole code:

```
print("Loading bot...")
import discord
import time
import asyncio
import datetime
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.utils import get
from webserver import keep_alive   
import os
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="t.", intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

[Other code]    
    
#Purge command    
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def purge(ctx, limit: int):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
        await ctx.send("Messages purged ")
        await ctx.message.delete()        

keep_alive()
bot.run('TOKEN)
```

My error:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYJNr.png)

Yeah, I use replit on python 3.8.5
Whats the problem?
Hope that you can answer my question.
I really dont know what to do, discord.py is such a weird programming language :/
Thanks
Evo

Comment: What's in `[Other code]`? You might have overwriten `commands` and made it a command somehow

Comment: @MrSpaar I removed the code as I thought this was not necessary. As you can see in the edit history OP has a command named `commands` which might cause the error.

Comment: Yup, that may be what's causing the error, `commands` not longer refer to `discord.ext.commands` but to the function

Answer (score 0):

import this in your file `from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions` this may help you
and make that line to `@has_permissions(administrator=True)`